# Break for loop and return result once found

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this coffeescript that I got from this question I asked earlier.

```
window.getObject = (theObject, key, val) ->
  result = null
  if theObject instanceof Array
    i = 0
    while i < theObject.length
      result = getObject(theObject[i], key, val)
      i++
  else
    for prop of theObject
      return theObject  if theObject[prop] is val  if prop is key
      result = getObject(theObject[prop], key, val)  if theObject[prop] instanceof Object or theObject[prop] instanceof Array
  result
```

It finds the result here:

```
return theObject  if theObject[prop] is val  if prop is key
```

Now it needs to stop the recursion and return with the result. Buts it not breaking out of the loop and thus setting result to null agian. Im sure Im missing something stupid!

**EDIT**

Now I changed so I would think this would work

```
window.getObject = (theObject, key, val) ->
  result = null
  if theObject instanceof Array
    i = 0
    while i < theObject.length
      result = getObject(theObject[i], key, val)
      i++
  else
    for prop of theObject
      if theObject[prop] is val and prop is key
        result = theObject 
        console.log "I found it"
        break
      console.log "I must not log after found it was logged"
      result = getObject(theObject[prop], key, val)  if theObject[prop] instanceof Object or theObject[prop] instanceof Array
    console.log "stop!!"
  result
```

The log looks like this in order:

```
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
stop!! ui.js:54
stop!! ui.js:54
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
I found it ui.js:46
stop!! ui.js:54
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
stop!! ui.js:54
stop!! ui.js:54
stop!! ui.js:54
stop!! ui.js:54
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
stop!! ui.js:54
I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
stop!! ui.js:54
stop!! ui.js:54
stop!!
```

Comment: To stop the loop, use the keyword `break`

Comment: like this ? if theObject[prop] is val
        if prop is key
           return theObject  
           break

Comment: If you do `return` from the whole function, you don't need to `break` the loop

Comment: I don't think "I must not log" is ever called after "found it". Could you please make an example with what arguments you call the function so we can confirm this behaviour?

Comment: model = getObject(item.attributes.data, "id",@options.id) . item is a backbone model with id and data, data is an object with many objects

Comment: Ill add the complete log..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log is correct, showing you the recursive calls:

```
 I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
     I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
         I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
             stop!! ui.js:54
         stop!! ui.js:54
     I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
         I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
             I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
                 I found it ui.js:46
                stop!! ui.js:54
             I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
                 I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
                     I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
                    stop!! ui.js:54
                stop!! ui.js:54
            stop!! ui.js:54
        stop!! ui.js:54
     I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
        stop!! ui.js:54
     I must not log after found it was logged ui.js:49
        stop!! ui.js:54
    stop!! ui.js:54
stop!!
```

<sub>(ignoring the Array part, after each "I must not log" another recursive level is called, and each call ends with "stopp")</sub>

As you can see, after the "I found it" the loop immediately stops.

> Buts it not breaking out of the loop and thus setting result to null agian

That happens on the next higher level. You are happily assigning `result = getObject(…)`, but *here* you are not breaking if the recursive call resulted in something (it's the same in the array loop).

However, instead of maintaining a `result` variable I find early returns easier to read (and you don't need `break`):

```
window.getObject = (theObject, key, val) ->
  if theObject instanceof Array
    for item in theObject
      result = getObject(item, key, val)
      return result  if result
  else
    for prop, item of theObject
      return theObject  if item is val and prop is key
      result = getObject(item, key, val)  if item instanceof Object or item instanceof Array
      return result  if result
  null
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need another one break if result not null. Something like this:

```
result = getObject(theObject[prop], key, val)  if theObject[prop] instanceof Object or theObject[prop] instanceof Array
break if result not null
```

You need to break your loop if object was found inside recursion call of this function.